# How to encode two signed integers into one number with the ability to recover them with proper signs?

Tags: encoding, bit-manipulation, decoding

There are multiple solutions on StackOverflow for unsigned integers. Wonder what to change in the following code to make it work for the signed integers too.

```
#works only for unsigned integers
bits=16
def encode(x,y):
    return (x<<bits) | y

def decode(encoded):
    #return (encoded>>bits, encoded & ~(~0 <<bits))
    return (encoded>>bits, encoded & 0xFFFF)

if __name__=="__main__":
    encoded=encode(3,-15)
    print(decode(encoded))
```

Comment: there's no difference except that you must do a sign extension instead of zero extension to get the value back

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "sign extension instead of zero extension" in this case?

Comment: [Understanding what sign extension does](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/252729/27052), [tag:sign-extension], [tag:zero-extension], https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

Comment: I understand individual bits and pieces. Can somebody put the solution here?